# jQuery: width() not working

Tags: jquery, width

here's my simple code:

```
var msgbox = $("<div style='width:320px;height:200px;'></div>");
alert(msgbox.width());
```

the alert gives me zero - what's wrong? why isn't it 320?

thx

Comment: Can you try adding a `&nbsp;` to the div?

Comment: Or try inserting the msgbox into the DOM before measuring its `.width()`.

Comment: isn't the `$("")` should be a selector rather then HTML?

Comment: @Ankit Jain: It can also be used to create HTML, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: then how does jQ differentiates b/w a selector and HTML? Is that first character as < is sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should insert your div in the document first. Or use `.css("width")` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first append the element to the DOM before trying to measure its size:

```
$('body').append(msgbox);
alert(msgbox.width());
```